# Sharing animated gif on facebook via share dialog

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

Does anyone know how to implement share animated gif via facebook share dialog , while i can get the facebook share dialog to work , the gif however remain static when shared to facebook post. Would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction

```
  FB.ui({
           method: 'share_open_graph',
            action_type: 'og.shares',
            action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                object: {
                    'og:site_name':'testing',
                    'og:url':'https://media.giphy.com/media/3fi9UrUWeDhXgf0zTL/giphy.gif',
                    'og:title':'testing',
                    'og:type':'object',
                    'og:image':'https://media.giphy.com/media/3fi9UrUWeDhXgf0zTL/giphy.gif',
                    'og:url': 'http://x.x.x.x',
                    'og:image:width': '800',
                    'og:image:height': '400'
                }
            })
          }, function(response){

          });
```

Comment: Hi @ray - Did you find a solution for this case?

Comment: hi @Martin , unfortunately i have not found a solution for this , have tried multiple way and it seems that by using facebook share open graph api to share gif , the gif itself would very much still remain static rather than the dynamic gif.